# Problem with nightandday.master displaying logo correctly on new Web Part Pages

Tags: image-display, web-part-pages

I work for a school district that is running SharePoint 2010 for our Intranet. I am currently working with our district technology trainer to create a site collection for him to use for his videos, resources, etc.  For his video and web resource section, I am creating Web Part Pages so that he can come in behind me and add his content...I started with two issues on all of the Web Part Pages that I created, the first was the left navigation not populating from the parent site; I have that issue solved.  The second issue I have not been able to find any resolution for not matter where I look.

On my created Web Part Pages, my logo above the ribbon tools is not displaying correctly.  On the sub-sites (this is the sub-site Video homepage [screenshot](http://lrrpclan.com/BB/Web20ResourceHome.jpg)) my logo shows as it should but on the sub-page ([screenshot](http://lrrpclan.com/BB/Web20ResourceWeb1.jpg)) the logo is replaced with the SharePoint generic image but the placeholder for the image is there (I have the image set as a link back to the parent site).

I have no idea what is going on, I have been into the nightandday code using SharePoint Designer and everything is correct in the code...the logo shows on all other pages/libraries...just not on the Web Part Pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!  Apparently on Web Part Pages, the default logo on these pages takes reign over any custom logo code put into the master pages.

To fix this:

Go to the page that has the offending default logo; On the Page ribbon tab, select Title Bar Properties; Scroll to the right and on the Web Part Page Title Bar properties input the logo URL; Click OK and done!

Comment: Awesom!. That was I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the URL for the image in the rendered page to see where it is coming from, which you can do from the browser, or using tools like the IE developer toolbar or Firebug. The most likely cause is that the image source is not pointing where you thought it was or it is relative to the base URL of the page.

If you give some more detail you might get some answers from people who know more about front-end development than me ;-)

Comment: While checking the URL of the image points me in the right direction, I have gone through all master pages to edit the code for that particular image to point to the custom logo and it still is not displaying correctly...I am still left with the default yellow box with the 3 people in it as those Web Part Page logos.  Can someone direct me on how to get to the "_layout" folder so that I can just replace the image there?  I have hunted as best I can with the time I have avialable but have had no luck finding that directory.

Comment: The "_layouts" folder maps to the SharePoint root folder on each server - something like C:Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS. You can modify the contents of this directory to achieve the effect you want, but it is a hack, and not the recommmended way of doing it.

Comment: Fair enough. I have gone through the 4 master pages and replaced /_layouts/images/siteIcon.png with /sites/edtech/PublishingImages/nd_logo.png to no avail. I am still new to SharePoint and my understanding is that whatever master page I set the site to is where it should pull the design from...I cannot for the life of me figure out where the code requiring /_layouts/images/siteIcon.png is.  I am just about at the point of changing the siteIcon.png to my logo file...any other recommendations or help?